# How to keep an incoming socket HTTP POST connection open after reading the body of the request

Tags: php, http, sockets

I have a HTTP server written in PHP which code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $address = '0.0.0.0';
    $port = 8080;

    $server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    socket_bind($server, $address, $port);

    socket_listen($server);

    while(true){
        $client = socket_accept($server);

        $request = socket_read($client, 1024);

        if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $request, $matches)) {
            $requestBody = socket_read($client, $contentLength);
        }

        $_POST = $this->getPostParameters($requestBody ?? "");

        // Do some things with the POST parameters

        $response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        $response .= "Content-Type: text/text\r\n";
        $response .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        $response .= "a cool response";
        socket_write($client, $response);
    }
```

But the response comes never to the client (a browser), as it seems to close the connection after the second socket_read() function (the one that reads the body). How can I keep this connection open and send a response?

There are checks to check whetever it is a POST request or not and getPostParameters works as expected.

Comment: You are assuming that the first socket_read will read the HTTP request header in full and only the header. This assumption is wrong - you cannot make any assumptions at all about the contents since the underlying TCP is a byte stream not a message protocol. *"as it seems to close the connection after the second socket_read() function"* - what  actual observation you have to support this statement?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich When I send something before the secound socket_read() function the client receives it. Otherwise not. What could I do different to read the header and the body correctly?

Comment: *"When I send something before the second socket_read() function the client receives it."* - it might be that everything was returned inside the first `socket_read´ so the second one will just blocking wait until the client closes the connection. *"What could I do different to read the header and the body correctly?"* - check what you got when reading, i.e. properly parse into HTTP header and body. Read more if the end of the header is not reached before parsing the header. Check the size of the body by parsing the header. Read more if needed, but adjust for what you've already read.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I can read as much as I want with the first read funtion. I only get the request body when reading the second time.

Comment: You use $server variable, but your server is in $FWAA_Server. Also ensure that your buffer of 1024 is big enough and have a look to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235372/php-socket-server-read-all-input